# create jquery array for ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

How can I convert the output of `drp.getDateRange` to an array so that I can post it via AJAX?

**I have updated this code to represent the advice given below**

```
<script>
    var drp;
    var myArray = [];
    function makedatepicker() {
        drp = $("#myDate").datepicker({});
    }
    function getRange() {
        var data = $("#myOutput").serialize();
        console.log("This is the serialized element");
        console.dir(data);

        $.ajax({
          url: "myurl.com",
          type: 'post',
          data: data,
          success: function(response) {
               console.log("This is the response from your ajax script");
               console.dir(response);
          }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        makedatepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just read some documentation, and drp.getDateRange() actually returns an array. How can i show that in an alert to see that it's working correctly?

Comment: You can debug the array with chrome dev tools or you can iterate trough it: `for( var key in array ) console.log(key + ': ' + array[key]);`. It's more effective than an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Note on JSON.  The default encoding will be url form encoded.  If you want the request to send the data as JSON, you will need to add..

```
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

also if you are returning JSON, you should add ...

```
 datatype : "json",
```

Not sure which scripting language your using on the back end, but if PHP, you can send back array data like this

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

I will add the JSON stuff to the sample code below.

End Update

---

If you use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) you an send it as ajax data and it will show up in your post or get array.

If you are working with an array, you might want to use [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

You can view an object or array in your developer tools (F12 in Chrome or FF), by using [console.dir(someObject);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

```
var data = $("#myOutput").serialize();
console.log("This is the serialized element");
console.dir(data);

$.ajax({
  url: "myurl.com",
  type: 'post',
  datatype : "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data : JSON.stringify(data),
  beforeSend : function (){
            console.log("Before Send: Data looks like..");
            console.dir(data);
  },
  success: function(response) {
       console.log("This is the response from your ajax script");
       console.dir(response);
       console.log("parsing JSON ...");
       console.dir($.parseJSON(response));
  }
});
```

Chrome Developer Tools Console, this is where you will see anything that you console.log or console.dir

[image]

You can check the JSON that is being sent by clicking the Network tab.  Then click the name of the ajax script and it will show you the data being sent.  (Also, clicking on the "response" tab will show you what is being sent back by your script.)

In the example below I am sending an ajax request using the above code and it is showing that the data is indeed a JSON object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried your suggested (edited about) but i am getting an error in the console.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: conosole is not definedCalendarUpdate.cshtml:273 getRangeCalendarUpdate.cshtml:133 onclick

Comment: I think `conosole` is not defined because you want to mean `console`. There is just a little bit error in the answer .)

Comment: @Gavin5511 Sorry it was just a typo.   It's obviously supposed to be 'console' not 'conosole'

Comment: Thanks NotoriousPet, i missed that typo too. I've corrected it, but i'm not seeing any JSON posted to my page using fiddler still? Is the above code correct (I've edited my original post)

Comment: What are you getting back in the console (see image in my answer).    I assume you are changing the #myOutput to the element you want to send.  Are you checking the POST array for the data ?  That is where it will be hwen it gets to your ajax script.   if you need it in JSON format I'll add and edit to my answer for JSON

Comment: Do you have a link to the fiddle??